# How can I concat two dynamic int-arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, merge, concatenation

My problem is to concat two dynamically allocated int-arrays into one of them.
I guess in principal from logic it should work...

I suggest that the `realloc(...)` inside the function is wrong.
I also tried it outside the function, but it's not working either.

```
void concatArrays(int *numbers1, int length1, int *numbers2, int length2)
{
  numbers1 = realloc(numbers1, (length1+length2) * sizeof(int));

  int counter = 0;
  for(int i = length1; i<(length1+length2); i++)
  {
    numbers1[i] = numbers2[counter];
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Now in the `main()`, i fill both arrays and at least I want to print out the new, longer array (numbers1).

```
int main()
{
  int length1 = 5;
  int *numbers1 = malloc(length1 * sizeof(int));

  // fill array1
  . . .

  int length2 = 4;
  int *numbers2 = malloc(length2 *sizeof(int));

  // fill array2
  . . .

  concatArrays(numbers1, length1, numbers2, length2);


  // print out "new" array (numbers1)
  int new_len = length1 + length2;
  for(int i = 0; i<new_len; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", numbers1[i]);
  }

  free(numbers1);
  free(numbers2);
}
```

Thank you for all your advices in advance!

Comment: Steps to do: Create a 3rd (target) array, big enough to hold the values from both arrays. Copy the first one to the target array, copy the second one to the target array (with offset). You might want to use `memcpy` or a derivate of it. Keep in mind that all allocated memory needs to be freed somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

realloc() returns a new pointer (usually) unless the new size is only slightly larger and can fit in an over-allocated array. You are not passing the new pointer 'numbers1' back to the calling function.